# cancelling tasks throws exception but task continues

Tags: c#

I am trying to cancel a long-running task which is simulated bay an infinite loop printing to the console. Cancellation token is invoked from the main thread after 2 seconds. Even though the output on the console says "token IsCancellationRequested   true", the loop continues. What is the problem here?

```
       private static void CancelingTasks2()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
            t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    throw new OperationCanceledException("cancelled on the token", token);
                print("printing for ever ...");
            }, token);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
                cts.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine("canceled");
            Console.WriteLine("task status  " + t.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("token IsCancellationRequested  " + token.IsCancellationRequested);
        }

        private static void print(string txt)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(txt); Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not use your Cancellation token in the "while" loop instead of "true" ?

Comment: Look e.g. [here](http://mikeadev.net/2014/03/cancel-a-loop-in-a-task-with-cancellationtokens-in-csharp/) how to add cancellation support to infinite loop.

Comment: This requires [cooperative cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) - the task must at some point check if it needs to exit.

Comment: the infinite loop was used just as an example for a long-running task, which I do not really know how long will take ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` and try to avoid mixing `Task` and `Thread.Sleep`. Use `Task.Delay`. If using `Task` then the code needs to be async all the way.

Your loop continues because there is nothing to break out of the loop.

A rewrite of the above example with proper syntax would look like this

```
public class Program {
    public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        await CancelingTasks2();
        Console.WriteLine("Exit");
    }

    private static async Task CancelingTasks2() {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

        var t = print("printing for ever ...", token);

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        cts.Cancel();

        Console.WriteLine("canceled");
        Console.WriteLine("task status  " + t.Status);
        Console.WriteLine("token IsCancellationRequested  " + token.IsCancellationRequested);
    }

    private static async Task print(string txt, CancellationToken token) {
        while (true) {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                throw new OperationCanceledException("cancelled on the token", token);
            Console.WriteLine(txt); 
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

And produce the following output when run

```
Hello
printing for ever ...
printing for ever ...
printing for ever ...
printing for ever ...
printing for ever ...
canceled
task status  WaitingForActivation
token IsCancellationRequested  True
Exit
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t53Fnl)

Comment: thank you, obviously I should have passed the token as a parameter to the "print" function. I actually inserted it into the loop as so ```while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) ```

Comment: @MarekPraski Yes that is the better approach. I had just moved what you had originally to for continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do an infinite loop in print, not checking the token cancellation more than once.

You should put you if inside the while loop:

```
         while (true)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException(
                    "cancelled on the token", token);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(txt);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
```

Comment: Why not just `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` rather than explicitly coding an `if` to do the same thing?

Comment: the infinite loop was used only to simulate a long-running task, which I do not know how long will take, eg. reading a large file from disc. In this case I would need to cancel reading but there is no loop